# Cannot compile a module importing Foreign.R

Tags: haskell, ghc

Here is a minimal module importing `Foreign.R` (note that it even doesn't use it):

```
-- test.hs
{-# LANGUAGE ForeignFunctionInterface #-}

module Test where

import Foreign
import Foreign.R 

foreign export ccall testR :: Ptr (Double) -> IO ()

testR :: Ptr (Double) -> IO ()
testR result = do
  poke result $ 1
```

This compilation fails:

```
ghc -fPIC -shared  -dynamic -lHSrts-ghc7.10.3 test.hs -o test.so
```

It gives:

```
Linking test.so ...
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: réadressage R_X86_64_PC32 vers symbole « Test_testR_closure » ne peut pas être utilisé en créant un objet partagé ; recompilé avec -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld : échec de l'édition de liens finale : Mauvaise valeur
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Sorry for French... In English it should look like:

```
Linking test.so ...
/usr/bin/ld: test.o: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 to symbol  « Test_testR_closure » cannot be used by creating a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld : failure edit final link : Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

There's no problem if I remove `import Foreign.R`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found [a fix here](http://tweag.github.io/HaskellR/docs/faq.html).

On Ubuntu, I did:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/ld" "ld" "/usr/bin/ld.gold" 20
```

There's no error anymore when I compile now.